# error accessing elements of array of std::pair

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, std-pair

I have defined an array of pairs as following:

```
std::pair<int,int> delta[4];
delta[0] = std::make_pair(0,1);
delta[1] = std::make_pair(1,1);
delta[2] = std::make_pair(1,0);
delta[3] = std::make_pair(1,-1);
```

but when I try to access the elements like:

```
delta[2].first
```

I get an error as following :

```
binary '[' : 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
error C2228: left of '.first' must have class/struct/union
```

Here is the function where I access it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int who_won(std::pair<int,int> &delta,std::vector<std::vector<int>> &grid);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::fstream input;
    input.open("E:\\in.txt",std::ios_base::in);
    std::string line;
    char ch;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;
    std::vector<int> row;
    while(input.get(ch))
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            grid.push_back(row);
            row.clear();
        }
        else if(ch != ',')
        {
            row.push_back(std::atoi(&ch));
        }
    }

    if(row.size()>0)
        grid.push_back(row);
    row.clear();

    std::pair<int,int> delta[4];
    delta[0] = std::make_pair(0,1);
    delta[1] = std::make_pair(1,1);
    delta[2] = std::make_pair(1,0);
    int l = grid.size();
    for( int i =0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        //auto & v = *i;
        for( int j = 0; j < l; ++j)
            std::cout<<grid[i][j]<<" ";
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }

    int winner = who_won(*delta,grid);
    if( winner == 0)
    {
        if( std::find(grid.front().begin(),grid.front().end(),0) == grid.front().end())
            std::cout<<"draw";
        else
            std::cout<<"play";
    }
    else if( winner == 1)
        std::cout<<"1";
    else if( winner == 2)
        std::cout<<"2";


    return 0;
}

int who_won(std::pair<int,int> delta[],std::vector<std::vector<int>> &grid)
{
    int l = grid.size(),connect;
    for(int px = 0; px < l; ++px)
    {
        for(int py = 0; py < l; ++py)
        {

            for(int i = 0;i < 4;++i)
            {
                connect = 0;
                for(int j = 1;j < 4;++j)
                {
                    if( grid[px + delta[i].first*j][py + delta[i].second*j] != grid[px][py])
                        break;
                    else
                        connect++;
                }
                if(connect == 4)
                    return grid[px][py];
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Your code looks fine (and compiles fine with GCC). Show the exact code where you're accessing the pair.

Comment: Compiles fine in Visual Studio 2010 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You method signature only specifies a reference to a single `std::pair` instance. You would probably want your signature to look something like the following if you want to pass an array of `std::pair`.

```
int who_won(std::pair<int,int> delta[],std::vector<std::vector<int>> &grid)
```

Comment: You forgot to change the prototype at the top of the file. Also you need to remove the *-operator in front of the 'delta' variable in the call to who_won.

Comment: @vivek: You need to fix this error *everywhere*. All declarations of your function have to be corrected. You apparently fixed the definition, but left the declarations unchanged. Of course, once you fix the declarations, you'll have to fix the call to `who_won` as well. Currently you are passing `*delta` as the first argument, which is incorrect. The `*` has no business being there.